# In Perl, when would you use a fat comma key/value syntax in a literal and NOT intend it as a hash-type structure?

Tags: perl

It has been pointed out to me that `("key" => "value", "key2" => "value2")` is *not* a hash literal, but rather a list, and how it is interpreted depends on the context you use it in.

No other language I know personally has a key/value syntax like this that can be interpreted in any way other than that the author intended to create a hash/map/associative-array/dictionary/etc, so I find this aspect of perl somewhat difficult to grasp.

What contexts are there in perl where you would use that syntax *without* intending it to create such a data structure, where it is intended to work in such a way that key/value pairs have no role?

Comment: [I've just been downvoted. How should I react?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121351/130608)

Comment: It would be unusual to see a comment to accompany a down vote, and with 12K reputation I'm astonished that you're not aware of that. What will gather more negative votes, as well as reducing your chances of getting a useful answer, is to rage about your unfair treatment and demand justice. I generally get two or three inexplicable down votes every day, and you should swallow your pride like the rest of us. The link that [**Sinan Ünür** left in his comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44037222/#comment75102093_44037222) is particularly useful and you should study it carefully.

Comment: I think it's a stretch to call this raging, but okay.

Comment: This isn't so easy to answer because few people are aware of the capabilities of the basic comma `,` which is pretty much the same as the "fat comma" `=>`.

Comment: Three angry rhetorical comments in a row, and you don't think you're raging? I'd hate to be around when you do,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any time you want to automatically quote a bareword to the left of a fat comma:

```
system ls => '-lh';
```

or

```
 my $x = [ a => [ 1, 2 ], b => [ 3, 4 ] ];
```

Any time you think it makes the code easier to see

```
join ', ' => @data;
```

Any time you want to say "into":

```
 bless { value => 5 } => $class;
```

`=>` is a comma, plain and simple. You can use it anywhere you can use a comma. E.g.:

```
 my $z = f($x) => g($y); # invoke f($x) (for its side effects) and g($y)
                         # assign the result of g($y) to $z
```

Just because one thing appears on the left side of a comma, and another thing appears on the right side of a comma, it doesn't mean that those two things constitute a key-value pair.

And, of course, if you are going to quote everything anyway:

```
 my %x = ("key", "value", "key2", "value2");
```

or if you want to quote nothing

```
 my %y = qw(key value key2 value2);
```

are both valid constructs.

So, the presence of a fat comma is neither a [sufficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necessity_and_sufficiency) nor a [necessary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necessity_and_sufficiency) condition for the presence of a hash.

Comment: Your edit to change the title to call it a 'fat comma' was very helpful. I did not know to call it that. I am already reading `Learning Perl` but I occasionally diverge to answer questions as they come up for me, as here.

Comment: @Aerovistae since you clearly are an experienced programmer, maybe _Beginning Perl_ by Curtis Poe is better suited for you than _Learning Perl_, which targets people that come without a strong tech background. Curtis' book on the other hand expects you to have some understanding of how to write code, and also gives you a nice round-trip through the ecosystem that comes attached to Perl, including its community and customs. I feel that might clear some things up for you.

Answer (score 4):

I regularly use this for calling `system`:

```
my $rc = system $command,
    -count    => 24,
    -file     => $filename,
    -verbose  => # no value
    -frobnitz => 'blat';
```

Any time I want a visual indication that these two values go together, I use the fat comma.

Answer (score 4):

`=>` and `,` are the same operator. They can be used interchangeably. They have nothing to do with hashes.

```
print($x, "\n");   ===   print($x => "\n");
$x=1, $y=2, $z=3;  ===   $x=1 => $y=2 => $z=3;
```

The only difference is that `=>` will auto-quote an identifier that immediately precedes it.

Answer (score 1):

Even though that's probably not the reason this is the case, one possible use for this is for situations when you want to have more than one value for the same key, but still want to maintain a "flat" structure (i.e. no nested arrays or hashes).

You could then read such a list as key-value pairs.

Example:

```
do_something(user => 1, user => 2, user => 3, action => "whatever");

sub do_something
{
    while (@_)
    {
       my $key = shift @_;
       my $value = shift @_;
       # ... do something with that key-value pair
    }
}
```

As soon as you turn that list into a hash, duplicate keys will result in a single entry (the last one).

Also note that the "context" is really simple: if it's assigned to a hash:

```
%hash = (a => 1, b => 2)
```

or in a hashref literal by enclosing it in `{}`:

```
$hashref = { a => 1, b => 2}
```

then you get a hash, otherwise it remains a list.

Note that the `key => value` notation is just one of many possible notations, you could also use the `qw` notation for instance:

```
%hash = qw(a 1 b 2);
```